# Magento upgrade 2.2.6 to 2.3.5-p1

Tags: magento2.3.5, magento2.3.5-p1

We are trying to upgrade Magento version to the latest release of Magento 2, We are getting composer errors kindly refer screenshot https://prnt.sc/tfj1o6 Kindly help me to fix it,

We have followed below post as well,
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/27013

Thanks in advance,

Comment: check this link --- https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/comp-mgr/cli/cli-upgrade.html and sample data magento follow this link --- https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/comp-mgr/cli/cli-rc1-samp.html

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the solution at https://meetanshi.com/blog/bypass-dependency-error-while-installing-extension-library-using-composer-in-magento-2/

Thank you.

Comment: Hello All still I am getting an error https://prnt.sc/tgu3b6

Comment: Hello All, Thank you, I have updated composer version and now successfully updated Magento version,